# Moving activity screen to background

Tags: android

I have a run in background button in my app, once clicked it will go to the home screen using this code:

```
moveTaskToBack(true);
```

The only problem is once I click the app icon to launch my app I get sent to the main activity in my app and not the activity where I used the moveTaskToBack method. Then if I click the back button from the main activity I get sent to the activity that contained moveTaskToBack. Are there any solutions to this problem so once I click the button with the moveTaskToBack and decide to launch the app again to resume it I get sent to the activity with moveTaskToBack and not to the main activity.

Answer (score 0):

dont call the movetobackground, just call home intent directly.

```
Intent homeintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
homeintent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
homeintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(homeintent);
```

Comment: It works on my app version through the debugger. I tried updating it to google play and I still have the same problem